# Adding Box to Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I've created a new box for use with the Hyper-V provider. When I try to add the box, it dies with the following:

```
PS C:\> vagrant box add sbx-misc-app01 .\img-misc-w2k16.box
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'sbx-misc-app01' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://C:/img-misc-w2k16.box
    box:
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:156:in `block (3 levels) in add': undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:461:in `with_temp_dir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:134:in `block (2 levels) in add'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:461:in `with_temp_dir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:115:in `block inadd' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:448:in `block in with_collection_lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:447:in `with_collection_lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:104:in `add'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:357:in `box_add'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:146:in `add_direct'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:120:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/plugins/commands/box/command/add.rb:78:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/plugins/commands/box/command/root.rb:66:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:46:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:269:in `cli'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.0.3/gems/vagrant-2.0.3/bin/vagrant:151:in `<main>'
```

Questions:

1. Is there a metadata file reference? I've searched. I'm sure it's in front of my face, but I can't find it.
2. Why am I getting the message "box: Box file was not detected as metadata."? I have a metadata.json file in my archive.
3. WTF is with the "undefined method `to_sym'" error?

Environment...

- Hypervisor OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise (10.0.15063)
- Guest OS: Windows Server 2016 Standard (64-bit)
- Provider: Hyper-V Vagrant 2.0.3
- box archive created with tar in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows
- box added from Powershell window

Contents of box...

C:\img-misc-w2k16\Virtual Hard Disks
C:\img-misc-w2k16\Virtual Machines
C:\img-misc-w2k16\metadata.json
C:\img-misc-w2k16\Virtual Hard Disks\img-misc-w2k16.vhdx
C:\img-misc-w2k16\Virtual Machines\AB56D8F5-4F71-4CCD-97E6-237713B79FD8....
C:\img-misc-w2k16\Virtual Machines\AB56D8F5-4F71-4CCD-97E6-237713B79FD8....

Contents of metadata.json...

```
{
    "name": "foo/windowsServer2016x64",
    "description": "This box contains Windows Server 2016 64-bit standard edition.",
    "versions": [
      {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "providers": [
          {
            "name": "hyperv"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is some confusion about the different aspects of the box.

so taking from https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/format.html

> Box File - This is a compressed (tar, tar.gz, zip) file that is
>   specific to a single provider and can contain anything. Vagrant core
>   does not ever use the contents of this file. Instead, they are passed
>   to the provider. Therefore, a VirtualBox box file has different
>   contents from a VMware box file and so on.
>
> Box Catalog Metadata - This is a JSON document (typically exchanged
>   during interactions with HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud) that specifies the
>   name of the box, a description, available versions, available
>   providers, and URLs to the actual box files (next component) for each
>   provider and version. If this catalog metadata does not exist, a box
>   file can still be added directly, but it will not support versioning
>   and updating.

The file `C:\img-misc-w2k16\metadata.json` is part of the box file - it is different from the box catalog metadata (used if you want to distribute your box) but the content that you share is a box catalog metadata.

reading further

> Within the archive, Vagrant does expect a single file: metadata.json.
>   **This is a JSON file that is completely unrelated to the above box
>   catalog metadata component**; **there is only one metadata.json per box
>   file (inside the box file), whereas one catalog metadata JSON document
>   can describe multiple versions of the same box, potentially spanning
>   multiple providers.**
>
> metadata.json must contain at least the "provider" key with the
>   provider the box is for. Vagrant uses this to verify the provider of
>   the box. For example, if your box was for VirtualBox, the
>   metadata.json would look like this:
>
> `{ "provider": "virtualbox" }`
>
> If there is no metadata.json file or
>   the file does not contain valid JSON with at least a "provider" key,
>   then Vagrant will error when adding the box, because it cannot verify
>   the provider.

so when you package your box, the Contents of metadata.json should be as

```
{
  "provider": "hyperv"
}
```

once you replace the content of your file, you can repackage the box and you should be able to run a VM from this box.

Comment: Done and done. "box: Successfully added box 'img-misc-w2k16' (v0) for 'hyperv'!" Thank you sir! Is there a schema or other reference as to what the metadata.json file in the box package can contain?